# How to fade different backgrounds but not the text

Tags: html, css

I am using different backgrounds for different sections of my website. I need help to fade all those background images but not the text on it.
[MY post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcSaX.jpg)

```
<div class="post" style="background-image: url(https://bensmann.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/New-Blue-Profile.jpg)">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>The Monarch</h3>
    <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
    <a href="/posts/p9chargingonwheels.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
```

```
.post {
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 background-position: center;
 opacity: 0.5;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unique classes for the posts and specify the background image in your CSS for the appropriate class.

```css
.post {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
}

.background:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background1:after {
  background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_FOSmVKg.jpeg);
}

.background2:after {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="post background background1">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>The Monarch</h3>
    <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post background background2">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>The Monarch2</h3>
    <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir....I have been struggling to do this for last 2 days. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @Prashant you're welcome. If your questions are solved, be sure to accept an answer. It's the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: Done Sir..! You are great